# For Oracle Database How to find when the row was inserted? (timestamp)

Tags: database, oracle, timestamp

This has been asked many times, but is there any new methods to find out the time when the row was inserted in Oracle Database?

I have already tried to find out using ORA_ROWSCN. But its not accurate. It shows the updated date i believe and dose not show if the row is inserted before a long time.

The previous designers thought that its not necessary to include the Date added and Date updated columns when they were designing the Database.

This has caused a lot issues when it comes to analyzing the data and auditing.

Please help, this would make my day.

Thanks in Advance  :

Comment: Short answer: not possible.

Comment: Would have been possible with fine grained auditing. Or your own built mechanism to audit. But, without any such thing, it is not possible.

Comment: "Previous Designers" didn't foresee it but it looks like now you have a prime candidate for a improvement. Fix the app so it puts it in a column and be done with it.

Comment: May be this might help you SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) FROM tabl1 where column1=2; SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP can be used in conjunction with the ORA_ROWSCN pseudocolumn to associate a timestamp with the most recent change to a row

Comment: link for SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions142.htm